# How do I commit the restful_authentication plugin to my git repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

How do I add a the http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master plugin  to my Rails project and the commit it to the git repo ? I need it to be committed with the project.

I have tried a few times but it's ignored by git.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From the README:

- either use git clone git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication
- or rename the plugin’s directory to be restful_authentication after fetching it.

Did you do that?

After doing a git clone, you'll want to `rm -rf restful_authentication/.git` to make your project happy to add it (or use submodules).

Answer (score 0):

Either way git status doesn't report anything that needs to be added, it's like it doesn't see it.

Comment: You must have some git ignores set up.  I can't reproduce this problem.  Here's a full transcript:  http://pastebin.com/fc78f7fd

Answer (score 0):

@Dustin has likely nailed your problem.

Also note that if you don't already have a "lib" directory in your project, I found the generator will fail:

```
ruby script/generate authenticated user sessions
```

So mkdir lib first.

I [posted a narration](http://tardate.blogspot.com/2008/10/restfulauthentication-and-openid-with.html) of restful_authentication + openid that covers these details and may be a little help.